# put output of 'time ./a.out' to a variable

Tags: bash, variables

I have used time command to execute program (like "xxx$ time ./a.out"), with output as follows,

```
real 0m7.250s
usr  0m10.395s
sys  0m0.026s
```

What I want to get is 0 and 7.250 as in 0m7.250s. I have tried "awk '{print $2}'", but without success; nothing output there.

PS: I have tried put output of time command to a file by using ">", also without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
pax$ tm=$((time sleep 1) 2>&1 | awk '/^real/{print $2}') ; echo $tm
0m1.002s
```

(substituting your own `a.out` command of course, `sleep 1` was just used for an example).

It creates a subshell for the `time` command and ensures that its standard error is sent to standard output instead (`time` specifically outputs its information to standard *error* so that it's kept separate from normal output of the program it's timing).

The `awk` command the captures the line starting `real` and outputs the second argument (the time).

Comment: You could also set the TIMEFORMAT environment variable to avoid the need to parse with awk. `((TIMEFORMAT=%R; time sleep 1) 2>&1)`

Answer (score 4):

The `time` command sends its output to standard error, so as not to interfere with normal program output.  You will want to use `2>&1` to redirect it where it can be captured.